# Flutter - How to crop the height of a webview?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, webview, crop

[![enter image description here][1]][1]I want to embed a web page but without showing the top bar. I tried putting negative margins to the webview but flutter don't allow that. I'm open to any possible solution. Thank you

The webview is at the body of my Scaffold, filling all the screen as you can see. The part of the webview (the "top bar") that I want to hide somehow, is marked in red.

```
 class _MainState extends State<Main> {
          static var titleText = 'INICIO';
          static int _selectedIndex = 2;
          List<Widget> _children;        
          static Size screenSize(BuildContext context) {
            return MediaQuery.of(context).size;
          }        
          void _onItemTapped(int index) {
            setState(() {
              _selectedIndex = index;                  
            });
          }  static Container inicio = Container(
        child: WebView(
          initialUrl: 'https://aom.org.ar',
          javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
        ),);    
          @override
          void initState() {
            super.initState();
            _children = [
              tienda,
              cursos,
              inicio,
              normas,
              contacto,
            ];
          }        
          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            var scaffold = Scaffold(
                appBar: AppBar(),           
                body: IndexedStack(
                  index: _selectedIndex,
                  children: _children,
                ),
                bottomNavigationBar: NavBar(Theme.of(context).primaryColor, _selectedIndex, _onItemTapped));
            return scaffold;
          }
}
```

Comment: Where do you want to embed a web page? What do you mean by top bar? Please provide some screenshots.

Comment: @BilaalAbdelHassan Check it now, I've added the screenshot so you can see what I mean

Comment: Can you please post your codes?
I think I can help you.

Comment: @BilaalAbdelHassan There is the code, hope you can help me